# error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: linux, boot, grub, opensuse, grub2

I get this error after installing opensuse 15.2 on a Dell Latitude E5410 (~year 2011), where the hard drive was replaced.
I tried default as well as manual setups and partitions.
I tried suggestions from https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found. But they do not really apply.

I only get a grub rescue console. I found the `(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub2/` folder, however, it is empty in grub rescue. Why? Booting the linux system help of the usb drive,
I see the many subfolders in `/boot/grub2/` including `/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod`.

Is the empty folder an issue with mounting points (`/`, `/mnt`, `/boot`, etc.) or file system (`Ext2`, `Ext3`, `Ext4`, `BtrFS`, `FAT`, `XFS`, `Swap`, `UDF`)? Or other boot setup (`legacy`, `uefi`)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution:

After booting with USBLive and login, I copied the `/boot` folder into another folder (`/boot2`). That folder was readable after restart (setting the prefix to that folder + `insmod normal` + `normal` it indeed tried to start linux, still it looked for some files in `/boot`).
Finally, I copied `/boot2` back to `/boot` and it just worked.